# How to select a nested webelement in html?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I would like to retrieve a webelement out of a nested html path using either css selectors or xpath.  My specific use case is that I would like to select the `i` element in the following snippet:

```html
<td class="headerActionsTd" data-rolename="Speaker">
  <div class="headerActions">
    <span class="addNewParticipantSection">
      <i class="icon fa fa-user-plus" title="Add New"></i>
      </span>
```

How do I obtain the `i` webelement for this using either css selector or xpath?

Comment: for which element i.e td or div or span or i , which element

Comment: for the i element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this xpath: `//td[@data-rolename='Speaker']//div//span//i[@title='Add New']`  or
css : `div.headerActions i`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.headerActions i"));
```

for multiple elements :

```
List<WebElement> users = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@data-rolename='Speaker']//div//span//i[@title='Add New']"));
```

Comment: I have several icons with the same elements, the only thing that change is the data-rolename from td, is there something more specific I can use

Answer (score 1):

A simple one would be this :

**CSS_SELECTOR**

```
i.icon.fa.fa-user-plus[title='Add New']
```

Note that, if there is multiple element with this css selector, then you have this facility to differentiate between them:

```
:first-child  
:nth-child(n)  
:nth-last-child(n)
```

More can be found at [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

**XPATH :** would be :

```
//td[@data-rolename='Speaker']/descendant::span[@class='addNewParticipantSection']/i
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said `data-role` only changes in the comment of the other person, here is the xpath you can use

```
"//td[@data-role='Speaker']//i"
```

Or

```
"//td[@data-role='Speaker']/div/span/i"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that you can attempt to locate elements inside other elements. For example, you could store the addNewParticipantSection div in a WebElement, then use that WebElement's findElement method to locate the i element within it. Like so:

```
WebElement section = driver.findElement(By.className("addNewParticipantSection"));
WebElement icon = section.findElement(By.tagName("i"));
icon.click();
```